# JavaScript: open links in new tabs

Tags: javascript

I would like to make a JavaScript that would put in each link the attribute `target="_blank"`, so that the link would open in a new tab. This is how I did it:

```
function open_links_in_new_tabs() {
    var links = document.documentElement.getElementsByTagName( "a" );
    for(var link in links) {
        link.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
    }
}

window.onload = function() { open_links_in_new_tabs(); }
```

But, this doesn't work. Do you see where the mistake is?

Thanks,

Ivan

Comment: For the record, the *reason* your original code doesn't work is because `link` is the index, not the actual link. See this example to understand better: http://jsfiddle.net/cNcFq/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `foo in bar` syntax [doesn't work](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/NodeList) on `NodeList` objects (a.k.a. "the stuff returned by `document.getElementsByTagName`").

Use a plain old `for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++)` (with `links[i]` instead of `link`, of course) loop and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `for... in` loop slightly wrong here. Try this:

```
for(var link in links) {
    links[link].setAttribute("target", "_blank");
}
```

**Edit:** Though my example works in this situation, Boldewyn is right in that this will give unexpected results if your script is not operating on elements.

Comment: This is not recommended for plain arrays, ordinary for loop is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this on stackoverflow, and it seems to work on all the links :)

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for(var i = 0; i < links.length; ++i) {
  links[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use jQuery, if you want to use jquery then here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').attr("target","_blank");
})
```